# Django how to add blank choice to queryset in form choices

Tags: django, django-forms

I have problem to add blank choice like '----' contain '' value to my choices with queryset.

I found couple of solutions but this doesn't work correct. I get a error like: 
**can only concatenate tuple (not "ValuesListQuerySet") to tuple**

**Forms.py:**

```
BLANK_CHOICE = (('', '---------'),)

class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('price', 'deadline', 'finished', 'client', 'platform')

    def __init__(self, request_client_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['platform'].choices = BLANK_CHOICE + Platform.objects.filter(client_id=request_client_id).values_list('id', 'name')
```

Can you give me some advice how to write correct?

Comment: You can just convert the queryset to tuple in the `__init__` method itself.
using `tuple(Platform.objects.filter(client_id=request_client_id).values_list('id', 'name'))`

Comment: Yes that's work... ahh very simple solution and i never think to use it :( Thank you

Comment: No problem. :) I'll put this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just convert the queryset to tuple in the `__init__` method itself.

```
def __init__(self, request_client_id, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OrderCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['platform'].choices = BLANK_CHOICE + tuple(Platform.objects.filter(client_id=request_client_id).values_list('id', 'name'))
```